# Inner call async behavior of EF DbContext during outer DbContext call ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my ASP.NET MVC website, users browse through books. They can choose to add each of the books in lists which they have created themselves.

When a user browses a book, there is a dropdown of all his lists below each book, which he can choose to add the book into. All good so far, but what I want now is for the dropdown to be aware if the book is already included in one of the lists of the user.

This is the relevant viewmodel:

```
public class UserBookListsMinimalVM    {
    public int ListId { get; set; }
    public string ListName { get; set; }
    public bool BookAlreadyInList { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the query I run to retrieve the items:

```
var userBookLists = await context.vwUserBookLists
                                 .Where(x => x.ListOwner == userName)
                                 .Select(x => new UserBookListsMinimalVM
                                 {
                                     ListId = x.ListId,
                                     ListName = x.ListName,
                                     BookAlreadyInList = context.List_Books.Any(y => y.ListId == x.ListId && y.BookId == bookId)
                                 })
                                 .OrderBy(x => x.ListName)
                                 .ToListAsync();
```

`vwUserBookLists` is a view containing list-related information and `List_Book` is the intermediary table between lists and books (containing books per list etc).

The generated SQL by EF is nested `SELECT` statements, mostly to account for the `BookAlreadyInList` property. (I don't know whether the query can be simplified, I'm open to suggestions)

Does the call to `context` during the `BookAlreadyInList` assignment "break" the asynchronicity of the entire function, seeing it is not `await`ed?

Comment: Have you observed any unexpected behavior with this code?  Is something not working?  It's not really clear to me what specifically you're asking.  A call to `.Any()` doesn't need to be awaited as it's not asynchronous.

Comment: Hi @David - it works fine (i.e. it returns the result as intended). My question is whether the non-async call to `context` during assignment of `BookAlreadyInList` 'conflicts' with the outer `await context` async call. Should `.Any()` become `.AnyAsync()`?

Comment: I don't think there's an `.AnyAsync()` (though you could quickly test that).  There wouldn't really need to be, since `.Any()` doesn't actually materialize anything from the data source.  It's translated into an expression tree for the backing data store like more other LINQ methods.  Only methods which actually materialize the data (like `.ToList()`) would necessitate asynchronous versions.

Comment: Thanks @David, there's `IQueryable<T>.AnyAsync()` which can be `await`ed - if I pass `async x` in the lambda I get "async lambda expressions cannot be  converted to expression trees"

Comment: The "call" to `context.List_Books` inside the query expression is simply translated to the corresponding database table `SELECT`, `JOIN`, `EXISTS` etc. There is no real execution of the query expression tree parts as code - they are like "placeholders", recognizable and translatable by the EF query provider.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan, it all make better sense now, especially after reading more about expression trees.

Answer (score 2):

It won't break you async operation, which will complete when ToListAsync() is done doing the job. There will be only one asynchrounous operation, which isn't broken by anything before that, the await/async contract will be respected, no matter what you do inside your query. Even if you tried to materialize some entities inside it, calling the synchronous ToList() for example (assuming EF would tolerate this), this synchronous call would be made in the background thread. You can't use AnyAsync inside your query because the sql provider can't translate an asynchronous operation, which is specific to c# and not to sql server.

That being said and more importantly, you could still ask yourself if EF is sending only one query to the database, or translating your query into several database calls (it could be the case, depending on the version you're using), or even doing some operations in memory. The best way to know what is exactly going on is to look at the output window if you can see the generated sql or to start a sql profiler watching the database while executing your code. 
In the latest versions of .net core, you can configure your dbcontext to throw exceptions when your expression tree cannot entirely be translated to sql and when some operations have to be made in memory. If you don't, you still get warnings though in the output window.